# Popup form in Django (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I know it's a very basic question, but I didn't find a simple explanation on how to do it.

I'm developing my app with Django and what I wan't is to create a popup in wich I can put a form so the user can authenticates. I just have no idea on how to do that. I know I have to use Jquery for that but that's it.

I'm just looking for hints or for good tutorials.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly what you are looking for is a Modal form. You need to pass the form from your view and render it on the template using jquery and submit it via ajax. Take a look in to this..

http://www.micahcarrick.com/ajax-form-submission-django.html

Comment: Ok thank you. Can I simply use a popup that redirects to an other view in which I put my form?

Comment: You mean you don't want to load the form in the pop up. If not, why do  you want to use the pop up

Comment: In my page I have a button that allows authenticated users to do something (follow someone). The button also appears if the user is not authenticated. But if he clicks on it, I would like a pop-up to appear in which he can authenticates (but i can still see what happens in the main page). Then, when he submits the form, or uses the facebook connect, the popup closes and the main page refeshes so that he can now use the button. I already have the form, in an other view. I just wan't to associate the popup to this view.

Comment: oh I see...sure you can use that view. You would just have to use the right url in your ajax call.